# Get unique values from sets in Pandas DataFrame columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a Pandas DataFrame which has the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"col1": [{1}, {5}, {}, {1, 2}], "col2": [{1, 2}, {}, {}, {3, 4}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

     col1    col2
0     {1}  {1, 2}
1     {5}      {}
2      {}      {}
3  {1, 2}  {3, 4}
```

My goal is to create a third column which will contain, for each row, the set of unique values from `col1` and `col2`. For the above example, the resulting DataFrame should be as follows:

```
     col1    col2          col3
0     {1}  {1, 2}        {1, 2}
1     {5}      {}           {5}
2      {}      {}            {}
3  {1, 2}  {3, 4}  {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I think this problem might be a good candidate for `apply` + `lambda` but I couldn't make it work properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: here's apply and lambda: `df.apply(lambda row: row['col1'].union(row['col2']), axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set [`union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union):

```
df['col3'] = [set().union(*x) for x in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

Output:

```
     col1    col2          col3
0     {1}  {1, 2}        {1, 2}
1     {5}      {}           {5}
2      {}      {}            {}
3  {1, 2}  {3, 4}  {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Note that your input is a mix of sets and empty dictionaries, this should be:

```
data = {"col1": [{1}, {5}, set(), {1, 2}],
        "col2": [{1, 2}, set(), set(), {3, 4}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```